# Google Sheets can't find Col4 using Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, valueerror, google-query-language

I made a budget spreadsheet that automatically updates from a form I fill out. I'm trying to use query to sum specific cells since sumif doesn't automatically include new entries and query would be easier to change each month.

Column A is hidden since it just contains the timestamp information.
Column B is the date that I made the purchase.
Column C is the category of the purchase.
Column D is the amount I spent.

[image: Here is an image of part of my spreadsheet.]

And here is the query formula I'm using to try to add all income together:

`=query(C152:D184,"Select Sum (Col4) where Col3='Income'")`

But I get the error "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col4". Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose a real range `C152:D184` in `{}` to use `ColN` (you'll have `Col1` and `Col2` here). Otherwise use letters (`C` and `D`). Also you are missing `GROUP BY` statement and `LABEL` (this one not to display a header for the sum).

So this:

```
=QUERY({C152:D184}, "SELECT SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 = 'Income' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''",)
```

Or this:

```
=QUERY(C152:D184, "SELECT SUM(D) WHERE C = 'Income' GROUP BY C LABEL SUM(D) ''",)
```

Or this:

```
=SUMIF(C152:C184, "Income", D152:D184)
```

Or this:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C152:C184, D152:D184 = "Income"))
```